# Realm Database get and delete Single object

Tags: android, realm

I save the location parameter when internet is off using realm database now how i get the single object from realm database to send the object to server and also delete that object at the same time

Comment: I made two service one service  checked if internet is on it send location parameter to server and if internet is off the second service is start which store location parameter in realm database.now if internet on again i want to send location parameter which store in my realm database to server and also delete form realm database

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: i save the locaation parameter using realm database when internet off like this.
1 31.75,74.56
2 32.45,74.90
3 31.75,76.98
Now when internt is on
I want to send location to server like this, 1st location object send to server and delete from realm database then 2nd object send and delete from realm database and carry on like this